# Auto submit not working on this script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, submit

I have been implementing all the javascript auto submit, but it reloads the page and does not submit the form, please help me.

```
<?php
ERROR_REPORTING(0);
include("../jesus/settings.php");
include("../jesus/connect.php");
#include("../jesus/header.php");
include("../jesus/func.php");

$errors=array();
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $link=cleanvalues($_POST["link"]);
    $cat=cleanvalues($_POST["cat"]);
    $img=cleanvalues($_POST["img"]);
    $comment=cleanvalues($_POST["comment"]);
    $description=cleanvalues($_POST["description"]);
    $prefix=cleanvalues($_POST["prefix"]);
    $format=cleanvalues($_POST["format"]);
    $folder=cleanvalues($_POST["folder"]);
    $title=cleanvalues($_POST["title"]);
    if(empty($title) || strlen($title)<4)
    {
        $errors[]="Your title is too short";
    }
    if(empty($comment) || strlen($comment)<4)
    {
        $errors[]="Your comment is too short";
    }
    if(empty($cat))
    {
        $errors[]="You must select a category";
    }

    $check=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM b_movies WHERE     title='$title'"));
    if($check>0)
    {
        $errors[]="FILE already Exists";
    }
    if(count($errors)==0)
    {
        $user=$user;
        $date=time();
        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO b_movies SET `title`='$title',
    `prefix`='$prefix',
    `format`='$format', `comment`='$comment', `catid`='$cat',     `link`='$link', `img`='$img', `by`='$user', `time`='$date'");

        if(!$insert)
        {
            $msg=mysql_error();
        }
        else
        {
            $msg="Upload successful";
        }
       $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM b_moviescat where id=$cat");
        while($cinfo=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $cname=$cinfo["name"];
            $cbody=$cinfo["body"];
            $kellyprefix=$cinfo["name"];
            $kellyprefix=kellychiprefix($kellyprefix);

            $idd=mysql_insert_id();

            $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO b_updates SET prefix='$prefix',  title='$title', folder='$kellyprefix', url='$idd', description='$comment', time='$date', img='$img'");

            header("location: /cron_jobs/sitemap_updater.php?msg=$msg?$title");
            exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($errors as $error)
        {
            $string.="$error<br/>";
        }
        echo"<div class='msg'>$string</div>";
    }
}
echo"";
//ERRORS
echo"<form name='kellychi' id='kellychi' action='' method='POST'>
<ul><li> title<br/><input size='100' type='text' name='title' value='$name'></li>
<li><center><select name='cat'><option value='4'>Naija Movies</option>";
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM b_moviescat");
while($cinfo=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $cid=$cinfo["id"];
    $cname=$cinfo["name"];
    $cbody=$cinfo["body"];
    echo"<option value='$cid'>$cname</option>";
}
echo"</select></center></li><li>Link<input size='100' type='text' name='link' value='http://highspeed-cbt.com/yt/getvideo.php?videoid=".$_GET['id']."&type=Download'></li>
<li><textarea rows='7' cols='60'  name='comment'>".$dtag."

Download And Enjoy...</textarea></li>

<li><input size='100' type='text' value='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$_GET['id']."/0.jpg' name='img'></li>
<li>prfx<input size='100' type='text' name='prefix' value='Download'></li>
<li>YT<textarea rows='7' cols='30'  name='format'><iframe width='640' height='360' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$_GET['id']."'     frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></textarea></li>
<li><center></center></li></ul></form>"; ?>


<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }, 5000);
</script>

<?php
#echo"<div class='center'><ul><span class='style4'></span></ul></div>";
#echo"<br>";

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You omitted tags that would enable the experts to locate your question. I have added the [php],[javascript] and [mysql] tags for you. It would also help if you said what results you get, and what you want it to do when working. It's all about the details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such element as: "$_POST["submit"]" in array. You need to use other field name like:

```
if(isset($_POST["title"]))....
```

If you put:
print_r($_POST) 
You will see all post values send. And you can choose different one or add hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
```

This will also work.

Comment: pls, can you copy the code, edit it and comment with it

Comment: You need only change this part:

$errors=array();
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

Into

$errors=array();
if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{